# Project output with incorrect processor architecture

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, build, tfs, msbuild

I have a main executable I have written in c#.  There are several dlls in the solution that it references as well.  I have created a nightly build in TFS that should build the entire solution as Release and x86.  When I compile the solution on a development machine, everything comes out correctly.  However, when it is compiled on the TFS build machine, the executable has its processor architecture marked as MSIL and the dlls fail to load with a BadImageFormat exception.  I have checked the build configuration for all projects and they are all set to Release/x86.  I have checked the build definition and it specifies Release/x86.  There are two other executables in the solution that both come out as x86.  What else can I do to force this exe to be compiled to the correct processor architecture?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when I went in and checked the solution properties, I got different results than when I checked build configurations. There, the executable was set to AnyCPU.

Answer (score 0):

Right clic on your project, click on `properties`, in the `build section` select `Platform Target` and set `Any CPU`

[image]

Ensure that you check in your csproj